# matlab find the last intersect gridpoint between two arrays

Tags: matlab, find, intersection

I have two functions `A` and `B=-kA` in a `mesh x=(1:1:100)`. I need to find the last grid point that A and B intersect, from the total 4 times criss-cross.

I used Matlab `find` :

```
find(A-B>0,1, 'last')-1;
```

which does not seem to work.

is any other way to do that?

Comment: If it's intersection that you're after, shouldn't it be `find(A-B==0,1,'last')`? Or better ``find(abs(A-B)<tolerance,1,'last')``

Comment: I guess you mean the point before the last intersection... your grid is probably too coarse to get anything close to numerical equivalence between the two functions, I am guessing.